How to cast to a 2022 Samsung TV without chromecast? "Available for specific video sites" showing up?
On both my Samsung TV, one a 2018 model (the 6 series) and the other a 2022 one (QN75QN90AAFXZA) I cannot cast my tabs from the Chrome browser, it says "Available for specific video sites", see pic below. If I add a physical HDMI Chromecast connector on the back ("Alberto Room TV" on pic below) it connects with no trouble. I googled but I could not find solutions. Am I supposed to buy another chromecast also for my 2022 QN75QN90AAFXZA? I am tired of swapping chromecast everytime I move from bedroom to living room. How can I fix this "Available for specific video sites" problem? It is there for every site.

